# Creating two frames and orienting them

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been working on a black jack game and I'm running into issues. Originally, my idea was to create 3 frames. A player_hand frame, a dealer_hand frame, and a buttons frame.

When I tried to do this I ran into a problem because the space dedicated to the buttons are being taken up by the player_frame on the left. A way to fix this is to order the frames in a specific way so that they don't "clash" or take each others space. However, I think a better way to do this would be to create 2 frames. The frame at the very bottom of the screen will be the buttons frame which should only take up a little bit of space. Above the buttons frame will be a frame that takes up the entire space left over and it will be a grid. How can I create a frame to take up the rest of the window space and turn it into a grid?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def hit():
    print("hit was pressed")

def stand():
    print("stand was pressed")

def new_hand():
    print("new hand was pressed")

'''
Creates the window
'''
window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Black Jack")
window.geometry("800x600")
window.configure(bg="#0C8702")

'''
Pulls one image and displays it to the screen
    - Will need to fix and update
'''
# image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("PNG/2C.png"), size="10x10")
# panel1 = tk.Label(window, image=image1)
# panel1.pack(side="left")

player_frame = ttk.Frame(window)
player_frame.pack(side="left")

'''
First card image
'''
image1 = Image.open("PNG/2C.png")
resize_img1 = image1.resize((80, 120))
real_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_img1)
panel1 = tk.Label(window, image=real_img)
panel1.image = real_img
panel1.pack(side="left")

'''
Second card image
'''
image2 = Image.open("PNG/2D.png")
resize_img2 = image2.resize((80, 120))
real_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_img2)
panel2 = tk.Label(player_frame, image=real_img2)
panel2.image = real_img2
panel2.pack(side="left")
'''
Creates the bottom buttons
    - Hit
    - Stand
    - New Hand
    - Quit
'''
buttons = ttk.Frame(window, padding=(20,10,20,0))
buttons.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")

hit_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="Hit", command=hit)
hit_button.pack(side="left",fill="x")
# hit_button.place(x=0, y=575)

stand_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="Stand", command=stand)
stand_button.pack(side="left",fill="x")
# stand_button.place(x=100, y=575)
# hit_button.pack(side="left")

deal_new_hand_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="New Hand", command=new_hand)
deal_new_hand_button.pack(side="left", fill="x")

quit_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="Quit", command=window.destroy)
quit_button.pack(side="left", fill="x")

window.mainloop()
```

[image: Output + changes and redesign]

This is the output I get, but I drew over it to show the redesign I'm looking to achieve.

The giant red boarder represents the frame I'm trying to create. The bottom buttons frame should be fine because the bigger frame (with the grid) will fill the window and the space on the left shouldn't be allocated to the grid frame.

In other words, how do i create that top frame?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following changes:

- use `player_frame` instead of `window` as the parent of `panel1`
- use `player_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=1)` to make `player_frame` use all the available space
- use `fill="x"` instead of `fill="both"` in `buttons.pack(...)`
- remove `fill="x"` from `.pack(...)` of the buttons

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def hit():
    print("hit was pressed")

def stand():
    print("stand was pressed")

def new_hand():
    print("new hand was pressed")

'''
Creates the window
'''
window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Black Jack")
window.geometry("800x600")
window.configure(bg="#0C8702")

'''
Pulls one image and displays it to the screen
    - Will need to fix and update
'''
# image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("PNG/2C.png"), size="10x10")
# panel1 = tk.Label(window, image=image1)
# panel1.pack(side="left")

player_frame = ttk.Frame(window)
player_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=1) # fill available space

'''
First card image
'''
image1 = Image.open("PNG/2C.png")
resize_img1 = image1.resize((80, 120))
real_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_img1)
panel1 = tk.Label(player_frame, image=real_img) # child of player_frame instead of window
panel1.image = real_img
panel1.pack(side="left")

'''
Second card image
'''
image2 = Image.open("PNG/2D.png")
resize_img2 = image2.resize((80, 120))
real_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_img2)
panel2 = tk.Label(player_frame, image=real_img2)
panel2.image = real_img2
panel2.pack(side="left")
'''
Creates the bottom buttons
    - Hit
    - Stand
    - New Hand
    - Quit
'''
buttons = ttk.Frame(window, padding=(20,10,20,0))
buttons.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")  # fill horizontal

hit_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="Hit", command=hit)
hit_button.pack(side="left")#,fill="x")
# hit_button.place(x=0, y=575)

stand_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="Stand", command=stand)
stand_button.pack(side="left")#,fill="x")
# stand_button.place(x=100, y=575)
# hit_button.pack(side="left")

deal_new_hand_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="New Hand", command=new_hand)
deal_new_hand_button.pack(side="left")#, fill="x")

quit_button = ttk.Button(buttons, text="Quit", command=window.destroy)
quit_button.pack(side="left")#, fill="x")

window.mainloop()
```